# Eclipse Debugger Loses Focus when Switching Files

Tags: eclipse, debugging, focus, keyboard-shortcuts

When debugging (Juno, SR1 on mac) I prefer using the keyboard keys instead of the mouse to step, step into, step out, go, etc.  But these keyboard shortcuts only seem to work when the editor is in focus.  The real problem happens when stepping in or out to another file.  The editor correctly shows the current line in the new file, but that file is **not** focused.  Consequently, I must grab the mouse and click in that view to re-enable the hotkeys.

This drags my debugging down to a crawl, as I'm constantly having to use the mouse instead of touch-typing. Searches don't find quite this issue.  Anyone with work-arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can change the key bindings:

Go to Window->Preferences - General->Keys, search for "step into", etc. And change in the select box: "When:" to "In Windows" (from "Debugging") or experiment with it to get result you want.

Setting it to "In Windows" I could "Step into" from any focused Eclipse component e.g. Package Manager, Console, Breakpoints, Servers, etc. And even when stepping into file.

Comment: Correction, seems to work sometimes.  User49767 below pointed out the bug reports on this issue.  I may have to degrade my version of Eclipse back to Helios or even Indigo (as suggested in the bug reports).  Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the Eclipse version. Eclipse 4.2  sucks on Windows and Ubuntu - Due to a bug

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372941.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing all sorts of issues with Juno on the Mac as well.  I'm about to degrade my Eclipse to an earlier version.  Thanks for the info--I thought it was just me.